# Issue in seeking audio in custom Jquery Audio Player

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Everything is working fine, the current time is being updated on timeupdate event and also when mousemove event is fired but after the mousemove event is completed, the audio starts playing back from where i started seeking.Ihave tried many solutions but none of them worked, I have been working on this for weeks now:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  const playPauseButton = $('#play_pause');
  const backwardButton = $('#backward');
  const forwardButton = $('#forward');
  const likeButton = $('#like');
  const volumeButton = $('#volume');
  const extraButton = $('#extras');
  const volumeSlider = $('.volume-slider');
  const volumeOutput = $('.volume-output');
  const lyricsButton = $('#lyrics-tab-button');
  const currentTimeSpan = $('.audio-player-tab .tab-time-info #currentTimeSpan');
  const durationSpan = $('.audio-player-tab .tab-time-info #durationSpan');
  const progressContainer = $('#progressBar');
  const progressBar = $('#progress');
  const progressSlider = $('#progress-slider');

  function formatTime(seconds) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    seconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
    return `${minutes}:${seconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}${seconds}`;
  }

  $(audio).on('loadedmetadata', function() {
    const duration = audio.duration;
    durationSpan.text(formatTime(duration));
    if (durationSpan.text() === "NaN:NaN") {
      durationSpan.text("0:00");
  } else {
      durationSpan.text(formatTime(duration));
  }
  });

  var progressSliderWidth = $(progressSlider).outerWidth();
  var isDragging = false;
  var startX = 0;
  
  progressSlider.on("mousedown", function(event) {
    isDragging = true;
    startX = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
  });
  
  $(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
    if (isDragging) {
      var progressContainerWidth = $(progressContainer).width();
      var sliderPosition = event.pageX - $(progress).offset().left - startX;
      sliderPosition = Math.max(0, Math.min(sliderPosition, progressContainerWidth));
      var currentTime = (sliderPosition / progressContainerWidth) * audio.duration;
      var progressWidthPixels = progressContainerWidth * (currentTime / audio.duration);
      currentTimeSpan.text(formatTime(currentTime));
      $(progress).css({
        "width": progressWidthPixels + "px",
        "background-color": "rgb(20, 247, 4)"
      });
      progressSlider.css("left", sliderPosition + "px");    
    }
  });
  
$(document).on("mouseup", function() {
    isDragging = false;
  });
  


  audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    if (!isDragging) {
      var currentTime = audio.currentTime;     
      currentTimeSpan.text(formatTime(currentTime));
      var progressWidth = (currentTime / audio.duration) * 100 + "%";
      $(progress).css({
        "width": progressWidth,
        "background-color": "rgb(20, 247, 4)"
      });
      var progressWidthPixels = $(progress).width();
      var sliderPosition = progressWidthPixels - (progressSliderWidth / 2);
      progressSlider.css("transform", "translateX(" + sliderPosition + "px)");  
    }


  });
  


  /*$('audio').on('timeupdate',function(){
    const currentTime = audio.currentTime;
    currentTimeSpan.text(formatTime(currentTime));
    const progress = currentTime / audio.duration * 100;
    progressBar.val(progress);
  });*/
 


  // Add event listener for when the audio starts loading
  $('audio').on('loadstart', function() {
      $('#loading').css('display', 'block');
  });

  // Add event listener for when the audio is fully loaded
  $('audio').on('canplay', function() {
    $('#loading').css('display', 'none');
  });

  // Event Listener For Play Pause Button
  playPauseButton.click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($(this).attr('class') == 'fa fa-play'){
      $(this).attr('class','fa fa-pause');
      audio.play();
    } else {
      $(this).attr('class','fa fa-play');
      audio.pause();
    }
  });

  extraButton.click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.options').css('visibility', function(i, visibility) {
      return (visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    });
  });

  volumeButton.click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.volume').css('visibility', function(i, visibility) {
      return (visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    });
  });

  volumeSlider.on('input', function(){
    const volume = $(this).val() / 100;
    audio.volume = volume;
    volumeOutput.text($(this).val()+'%');
    if($(this).val() == 0){
      volumeButton.attr('class','fas fa-volume-mute').css('color','orangered');
    } else if($(this).val() !=0 && $(this).val() <= 50){
      volumeButton.attr('class','fas fa-volume-down').css('color','white');
    } else{
      volumeButton.attr('class','fas fa-volume-up').css('color','white');
    }
  });

  lyricsButton.click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.lyrics-tab').css('visibility', function(i, visibility) {
      if (visibility == 'visible') {
      $(this).fadeOut(500, function(){
      $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
      });
      $(this).find('.lyricstab-info').fadeOut(500, function(){
      $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
      });
      } else {
      $(this).fadeIn(500, function(){
      $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
      });
      $(this).find('.lyricstab-info').fadeIn(500, function(){
      $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
      });
      }
      });
      
     // Add event listener for when the audio is seeking
$('audio').on('seeking', function() {
  $('#loading').css('display', 'block');
});

// Add event listener for when the audio is done seeking
$('audio').on('seeked', function() {
  $('#loading').css('display', 'none');
});
      
      /* Format Time
      function formatTime(seconds){
      var minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
      var seconds = Math.floor(seconds - minutes*60);
      if(seconds < 10){
      seconds = '0'+seconds;
      }
      return minutes+':'+seconds;
      }*/
    }); 
      });
```

```css
/* Audio Container */
 .audio-player{
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 5px;
    height: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;

 } 
 
 .album-image{
   position: absolute;
   top: 16px;
   margin-left: 10px;
 }

 .album-image img{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 5px;
 }  

 .player-info{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
 }

 /* Progress Bar Container */
.progress-bar-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  /* Progress Bar */
  .progress-bar {
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 67px;
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
  
  /* Progress Bar Filled */
  .progress-bar-filled {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f44336;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

.player-progress{
    position: relative;
    top: 34px;
    left: 57px;
}

.audio-info{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.player-info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 70px;
    left: 187px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
}

.time{
position: relative;
left: 131px;
top: 76px;
color: white;
font-size: 25px;
}

.player-buttons {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 75px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: right;
}

.player-buttons button {
    color: white;
    background: green;
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.player-buttons button:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.control-buttons{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        bottom: 47px;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
}

.control-buttons i {
    font-size: 61px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.control-buttons i:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.lyrics {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 1295px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}


.audio-player-tab{
    left: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.player{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 99%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #333;
}

.audio-player-tab .album-art{
    position: inherit;
}

.audio-player-tab .album-art img{
    width: 100px;
}

.audio-player-tab .progress-bar-container{
    position: relative;
    bottom: -24px;
}

.audio-player-tab .progress-bar-container #progressBar{
    position: relative;
    left: 47px;
    bottom: -2px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: white;
}

.audio-player-tab .progress-bar-container #progressBar #progress{
    position: relative;
    height: inherit;
}

.audio-player-tab .progress-bar-container #progressBar #progress-slider{
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;
}

.audio-player-tab .progress-bar-container #progressBar #progress-slider:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.audio-player-tab .buttons{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    top: 35px;
    left: 440px;
    font-size: 30px;
    word-spacing: 20px;
}

.audio-player-tab .player .buttons i:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.audio-player-tab .audio-info{
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: 120px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.audio-player-tab .extra-buttons{
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 35px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    word-spacing: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.audio-player-tab .extra-buttons:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.audio-player-tab .extra-buttons #volume:active,#extras:active{
  background-color: rgb(11, 233, 11);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.audio-player-tab .like{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 250px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.audio-player-tab .like:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.options{
   z-index: 1;
   visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    bottom: 111px;
    right: 5px;
    height: 235px;
    width: 155px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius:  5px;
}


.options .eop{
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.options .eop:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(16, 221, 16);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.audio-player-tab .volume{
  visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #333;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.audio-player-tab .volume input[type="range"]{
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.lyrics-tab{
  z-index: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 110px;
  height:1250px;
  width: 66.2vh;
  background-color: #333;
}

.lyrics-tab .lyricstab-info{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.audio-player-tab .tab-time-info{
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 120px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.audio-player-tab .tab-time-info #currentTimeSpan{
  position: relative;
  left: -18px;
}

.audio-player-tab .tab-time-info #durationSpan{
  position: relative;
  left: 763px;
}

#loading{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .audio-player-tab .progress-bar-container #progressBar {
        left: 50px;
        bottom: -4px;
        width: 94.7%;
        background-color: white;
    }

    .audio-player-tab .buttons {
        left: 937px;
    }

    .audio-player-tab .tab-time-info #durationSpan {
        left: 1701px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test1.css">
</head>
      <div class="audio-player-tab">
        <div class="lyrics-tab">
          <div class="lyricstab-info">Song Name -  Artist</div>
        </div>
        <div class="player">
          <div class="buttons">
            <i class="fa fa-step-backward" id="backward"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-play" id="play_pause"></i>
            <!--<i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin" id="loading"></i>-->
            <i class="fa fa-step-forward" id="forward"></i>
          </div>
          <audio src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3" id="audio" type="audio/mpeg">
        <div class="album-art">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1574169208507-84376144848b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=879&q=80" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="audio-info">
          <div class="song-name">Song Name</div>
          <div class="artist-name">Artist Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="like">
          <i class="fa fa-heart" id="like"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="extra-buttons">
          <div class="volume">
            <div class="volume-output">64%</div>
            <input type="range" class="volume-slider" min="0" max="100">
          </div>
        <i class="fa fa-volume-up" id="volume"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-bars" id="extras"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-time-info">
          <span id="currentTimeSpan">0:00</span>
          <span id="durationSpan">6:00</span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-bar-container">
          <div id="progressBar">
            <div id="progress"></div>
            <div id="progress-slider"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </body>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </html>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what the issue is supposed to be here, because I can't tell by looking at your rendered snippet. Are you trying to use your own draggable slider element to navigate to a specific position in the audio? Then I would expect to see an assignment to the `currentTime` property, or a call of the `fastSeek` method somewhere in your code, but I can't find either anywhere.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I am trying to use my own draggable slider element to navigate to a specific position in the audio. Can you elaborate your suggestion a little, like what you are asking to do.I didn't get it.

Comment: You will need to _set_ the position of the audio element, because that will not automagically happen just because you drag some slider, that has no real connection to the audio element to begin with. And I mentioned the property and a method that can be used to do that. If you need details on either - please go read up on them, for example in the MDN (Mozilla Developer Network.)

Comment: @CBroe Take a look at my jsfiddele: https://jsfiddle.net/crazyprogrammer17/d2xt0h8a/11/